# How to get the new URL after URL redirect

Tags: javascript, http, url, redirect

http://www.mcmaster.ca/academic/faculties.cfm

When I type the URL above in the browser, it redirects me to a new URL: http://www.mcmaster.ca/vpacademic/faculties.html

Is there any method that I can use to obtain the redirect URL given the first one?

Answer (score 0):

To do this programatically it will be a little difficult since the original URL redirects to the second URL via a client side redirect (with JavaScript) and not with a server side one (with a `301` or `302` and a `Location` header).

This particular site is using this JavaScript code to redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location="http://www.mcmaster.ca/vpacademic/faculties.html";
//-->
</script>
```

You could use what is called a headless browser (such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)) to programatically load the first URL and execute the JavaScript to end up at the second URL.

This answer provides some more details about headless browsers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20231244/1547546.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this in your code in order to track and log referrer URLs :

String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");